# User-defined operators in Fortran

Tags: fortran, user-defined-functions, fortran90, user-defined-types, fortran95

I had a question about the correct way of programming user-defined operators in Fortran. To be more specific, I will provide the example of my problem. I am working on creating a user-defined data type for spherical particles called 'Particle'. I want to define an operator that takes an existing array of Particle objects and adds a new Particle object to it. I was wondering how I would go about defining user defined operators to do such an action.

Currently I have, within the type definition for Particle, the following lines:

```
procedure, public:: addNewParticleTo
generic:: operator(.spawn.) => addNewParticleTo
```

Following which, I have a subroutine that is defined as follows:

```
subroutine addNewParticleTo(a_LHS, a_RHS)
  implicit none
  class(Particle), dimension(:), allocatable, intent(in):: a_LHS
  class(Particle), dimension(:), allocatable, intent(inout):: a_RHS
  <rest of the code>
end subroutine addNewParticleTo
```

I intend for the operator to be invoked as:

```
particle .spawn. particleArray
```

I was wondering if this is the correct way to go about doing this. Any suggestions or advise on this will be very helpful.

Comment: I was under the impression that `operator` requires a `function`, not `subroutine`.

Comment: Could you suggest how I would define the corresponding function then for defining such an operator in general ? I guess I have used such a construct before for overloading the assignment operator for creating copy constructors - and there I had used subroutines.

Comment: You ought to be able to do it simply by swapping `subroutine` with `function` and then using `NewparticleArray = particle .spawn. OldparticleArray`.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the comments, you will need to have the `operator` code as a `function`.  Further, each input would need to be `intent(in)`.  This would indeed allow something like `array = particle .spawn. array`.

However, another change is required to your subroutine: one of your arguments should be a scalar.  [The first, unless you play with the `pass` attribute.]

```
function addNewParticleTo(A, B) result(C)
  class(particle), intent(in) :: A
  class(particle), allocatable, intent(in)  :: B(:)
  class(particle), allocatable :: C(:)
  ! ... code to do the appending
end function
```

Finally, my advice is that having this as a type-bound operator is making things quite complicated, with the polymorphism and so on.  Also, `array = particle .spawn. array` seems very unintuitive.

Instead, just a plain subroutine so that `call add_to_particle_array(all_particles, new_particle)` works seems cleaner.  This is closer to your original code, but doesn't answer your question about operators, alas.