# What does .i. refer to in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I usually only use R or Python so my understanding of Fortran is really limited. But currently I have to make some subroutines from a Fortran program available to R. I came across this line in one of the subroutines that I need to "export".

```
R2inv(1:(i2-i1-1),1:(i2-i1-1)) = .i.(corrMat((i1+1):(i2-1),(i1+1):(i2-1)))
```

And I cannot figure out what the `.i.` is supposed to do there. There is an `i` variable declared but it does not seem to be used for that subroutine.

My compiler, gfortran also can't get over that term.
I tried googling but the term is not really "googlable".

As the IMSL libraries are used maybe it is an expression from those.

Comment: Things like `.i.` refer to _user-defined operators_, such as can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20054059/3157076).  Hopefully that search term gives you enough to work with, but if you need more help you'll likely need to provide more context.  The compiler surely complains with a relevant error message, for example.

Comment: Thanks @francescalus it helpde I found the opereator in one of the manuals of the IMSL libraries and refers to the inverse of an matrix (just in case anyone will ever stumble over teh same question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the [manual](http://docs.roguewave.com/imsl/fortran/2018.0/pdf/FortranFC-v2018.0.pdf) of IMSL Fortran library, on page 49:

> CHAPTER 10: LINEAR ALGEBRA OPERATORS AND GENERIC FUNCTIONS
>
> (...)
>
> OPERATORS: `.i.`
>
> Computes the inverse matrix, for square non-singular matrices, or
>   the MoorePenrose generalized inverse matrix for singular square
>   matrices or rectangular matrices.

As well said by @francescalus, identifiers surrounded by dots in fortran are operators.
Besides intrinsic operators like `.lt.`, custom operators like this can be written to be used as convenient shorcuts to common functions.

OTOH, this kind of stuff must be very well documented to not become a mistery to someone seeing the code. In this case, a name just a little more meaningful `.inv.` would arguably had been a better fit.